# Access related objects in Core Data

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I've made a relationship between my `Songs` and `Playlists` entities. Now I'm trying to access the `Songs` in the selected `Playlist`. The selected playlist is saved in the object

```
optionsSingle.selectedRowNumber
```

I have this fetch method where I'm accessing all the songs object and save them in a `NSMutableArray` called playlists. How do I only fetch the songs which are related to the give playlist object (`optionsSingle.selectedRowNumber`)?

```
- (void)fetchDevices {

    NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext = [self managedObjectContext];
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:@"Playlists"];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Playlists" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];    

    playlists = [[managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:nil] mutableCopy];
}
```

Core Data Model:

[image]

Comment: Can you post your `Song` and `Playlist` model? It seems like your entity relations are not set up properly. A playlist should have a list of songs, that should be enough.

Comment: Say something about your model. And entities should have a singular name, e.g. `Song` and `Playlist`

Comment: `selectedPlaylist.songs` should give you the songs you are looking for...if `songs` is the relationship name

Comment: ...or `[selectedPlaylist valueForKey:@"songs"]`. Where `selectedPlaylist` is the chosen playlist. In both cases, you receive a `NSSet` back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some issues with your code and model. Entity classes should be named singular (`Song` and `Playlist`).

The method is called `fetchDevices` (seems like a copy&paste error and should rather be `fetchPlaylists` or something?)

You are doing too much to retrieve them. The method can be reduced to:

```
- (void)fetchPlaylists {

    NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext = [self managedObjectContext];
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Playlist"];    

    playlists = [[managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:nil] mutableCopy];
}
```

You can also try to reduce the relation so that one `Playlist` has many `Song`(s). That should be enough for your requirements. Then you can proceed and access a list of songs that will automatically be fetched with your playlist.

Comment: Good answer, but many-to-many relationships do not need a join table. Only justification is if the join table needs to contain additional attributes. Otherwise it is *not* "error prone".

Comment: Ok, thank you. I am using many-to-many mostly in Rails where it seems highly recommended.

Answer (score 2):

I think you have a better design choice. While the corrections suggested by Sebastian are very important, you should redesign your table view. (I infer it is a table view displaying your playlists from your question).

You should use a `NSFetchedResultsController` rather than creating an array and populating your table with the contents of the array. The FRC will take care of all the fetching and memory management specific for the table view.

You can get a working example of a `NSFetchedResultsController` easily by opening the master-detail template ("New Project" in Xcode) and checking the "Core Data" option.

Now you can get to the playlist very easily:

```
Playlist *playlist = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
```

You will find that it will be much easier to write clean, concise and readable code.